# Imperatives, Sentences, not Complete Sentences?

Tags: imperative-sentences

I think someone wrote, "go", may seem a sentence, maybe, a complete sentence.

It seems I read, "Read the sentence", and maybe, "Don't worry".

They seemed to contain periods. May these seem complete sentence? May they seem, "imperatives"? There may seem, imperative sentences, declarative sentences, interrogative sentences and exclamatory sentences?

I may not get how you may write, "don't worry" like a complete sentence.

Comment: Just a note: *seem* means having the appearance of while not necessarily being something.  Most of your statements using *seem* would be better off without it- either your *did* or you *didn't*.  So if you read a sentence, then say, "I read a sentence.":  *I think someone wrote, " 'Go.' is a complete sentence." as is 'Don't worry.'"  These sentences contain periods. Are these complete sentences? Are they **imperatives**? (I know that sentences can be classified as imperative, declarative, interrogative, and exclamatory.)  I don't understand how "Don't worry." forms a complete sentence.*

Comment: Imperatives are complete sentences, even if the subject you is not indicated as a word,  it is understood as definition of the verb form imperative. If you say  "Go" to someone nobody will ask "who?". In Latin, German, French imperatives have rests of personal endings, veni/venite, viens/venez, komm/kommt. In English the imperative works without personal endings, but the function can't be misunderstood.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Declarative and interrogative main clauses** in English generally need subjects to be complete:

> **She** mowed the lawn.
>   Did **she** mow the lawn?

But **imperative clauses** are different.  They usually don't include explicit subjects:

> <s>You</s> read the sentence.
>   <s>You</s> don't worry.

Semantically, the subject is *you* (the listener or reader).  It doesn't need to be stated explicitly.

There are exceptions, however, with explicit subjects:

> **Nobody** move!

A bank robber might order everyone in the room not to move by saying "nobody move".  In this example, the subject is *nobody*.

Comment: I guess, "Take on a new project, pick up a new skill, or start a new hobby" may seem like those? This may seem like three imperative clauses?

Comment: @saySay Correct!  All of those are imperative clauses.  In each of those clauses, *you* is understood as the subject even though it's not expressed.

Answer (score 0):

All three of your examples of imperatives. All three could be complete sentences.  For each one, the implied subject is "you".

To write them as complete sentences, just capitalize the first word, and end with a period (or an exclamation point, if more emphasis is desired.)

- Go.
- Read the sentence.
- Don't worry!